# Extract hardcoded values to referenced variables not working as expexted

Tags: bash, shell

I'm attempting to refactor my bash function in order to hold some values that were within the main command in variables instead, however I am facing issues...

Original:

```
echo MY_PASSWORD | sudo -S ~/filename;
```

new

```
systemPassword="MY_PASSWORD"
location="~/filename"
echo $systemPassword | sudo -S $location;
```

Performing my new command is met with the error:

```
Password:sudo: ~/filename: command not found
```

Have I missed something obvious in order to extract my password and file path out?

Comment: with `location="~/PATH_TO_FILE"` it's not possible the error is `sudo: PATH_TO_FILE: command not found`. please post real code and real error messages. or you can post a [repro].

Comment: @pynexj I edited the Q to be as close as possible to the real code - All that was changed was `~/PATH_TO_FILENAME` was changed to `~/filename`. The error message remains the same with the same substitution.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that bash doesn't expand ~ as the home directory, when inside double quotes. Try using the `HOME` variable:

```bash
systemPassword="MY_PASSWORD"
location="$HOME/PATH_TO_FILE"
echo $systemPassword | sudo -S $location;
```

Comment: it's not clear how OP wants to expand `~`. to current user's home or to sudo'ed user's home?

Comment: @Miguel A man of the Mac I see! I knew it would be something as simple as this! Cheers